# XUnit Runner for Xamarin Devices IOS install App via Command Line on Jenkins

Tags: xamarin.ios, xunit

As part of a CI build process I would like to build, then run an IOS XUnit Runner (https://github.com/xunit/devices.xunit) on the build server and then eventually monitor its results.

After the app is built, here is where I have got to to try and load the app on a simulator -

> /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch
>   --sdkroot /Applications/Xcode.app -launchsim Users/me/Dev/mydir/xunit.app --device=iphone

gets me

> error MT1212: Failed to create a simulator where type = iPhone 4s
>   (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s) and runtime = iOS
>   11.2 (11.2 - 15C107) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-2.

changing --device to ipad gets a similar error related to IPads.

I can use

instruments -w help

to get me a list of these sims (shortened) -

> iMac 2017 [CCC8A9DA-BB70-58B4-9653-39EEE0789847] 
>   iPhone (11.2.6) [28061ef6effc9e9e12a8f5932d5e07c219340f3e]
>   iPhone X (11.2) [77911DFD-7E53-4CAD-AEE3-A119EC22D14E] (Simulator)

But I have no luck on how I START and load the app on a SPECIFIC simulator from the command line from this list.

Also, is there anyway I can see the command lines that Xamarin calls to start and install the app on the device when it kicks off debug etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this after further investigation using -

```
xcrun simctl
```

and its various options for controlling and installing apps on IOS Simulators.

If you copy the GUID from the *instruments -w help OR xcrun simctl list* call

[**28061ef6effc9e9e12a8f5932d5e07c219340f3e**] iPhone X (11.2) [77911DFD-7E53-4CAD-AEE3-A119EC22D14E] (Simulator)

You can use calls such as -

Shutdown Sim

```
xcrun simctl shutdown 28061ef6effc9e9e12a8f5932d5e07c219340f3e
```

Boot Sim

```
xcrun simctl boot 28061ef6effc9e9e12a8f5932d5e07c219340f3e
```

Once you have booted a single sim, you do not need to used the GUID anymore, you can use the shorthand "booted" identifier -

Erase Sim

```
xcrun simctl erase booted
```

To Install an app

```
xcrun simctl install booted path/to/your.app

xcrun simctl launch --stderr=/somepath/err.txt booted path/to/your/appbundle.id
```

to Launch an installed

```
 xcrun simctl launch --stderr=/users/matthewwaring/xunit.txt  79503DCD-A914-4128-BDD9-E68C867F5AA9 com.biid.sdk.core.xamarin.binding.ios.xunit
```

And so on.

We have integrated these calls in a Jenkins script and all works great.